# Clarification on the meaning of interpretation of a template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

[[temp.res]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8.4) reads

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: [...]
>
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
> - the **interpretation** of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the **interpretation** of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template. [...]

What does *interpretation* here mean? Does it mean that each token must be interpreted as the same operator/entity/whatever grammatical construct, aka syntactically equivalent? Or does it mean that it has to also be semantically equivalent, as in the equivalence defined by the [ODR rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def.odr-6)?

As a side note, [[temp.variadic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#variadic-7) has the sentence

> [...] Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic interpretation of the enclosing construct [...]

Which has the explicit "syntactic".

Comment: Does reading [the issue description](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1850) help? I'd say "interpret" is just... what does that construct mean per the rules of the abstract machine. See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34170836/2069064) from T.C.

Comment: @Barry I think the example from T.C. is crystal clear, not so much the issue description :P. Should I mark as duplicate?